# How to fix ValueError in fitting GMM using sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, scikit-learn, gmm

I am trying to use GaussianMixture model for image segmetation, so I used 2 components, covariance matrix type="full" and tried to run using Spyder3.6 which comes with anaconda. Here's the code:

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imshow
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
import graph_tool.all as gt
from graph_tool.all import *

X=imread('2.jpg')
old=X.shape
X=X.reshape(-1,3)
gmm=GMM(covariance_type='full', n_components=2)
gmm.fit(X)
clusters=gmm.predict(X)
clusters=clusters.reshape(old[0],old[1])
```

But it shows ValueError and positive definite exception and I can't figure out why? Here's the trace of error.

`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py", line 318, in _compute_precision_cholesky
>       cov_chol = linalg.cholesky(covariance, lower=True)
>     File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py", line 81, in cholesky
>       check_finite=check_finite)
>     File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_cholesky.py", line 30, in _cholesky
>           raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor not positive definite" % info)
>   numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 2-th leading minor not positive definite
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/madhur/Desktop/Project/graphcutmaterials/test.py", line 19, in 
>       gmm.fit(X)
>   File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/base.py", line 207, in fit
>       self._initialize_parameters(X, random_state)
>   File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/base.py", line 157, in _initialize_parameters
>       self._initialize(X, resp)
>     File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py", line 643, in _initialize
>       covariances, self.covariance_type)
>     File "/home/madhur/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py", line 320, in _compute_precision_cholesky
>           raise ValueError(estimate_precision_error_message)
>
> ValueError: Fitting the mixture model failed because some components have ill-defined empirical covariance (for instance caused by singleton or collapsed samples). Try to decrease the number of components, or increase reg_covar.

`

Comment: Whats the shape of X here?

Comment: 80*120*3 is the shape of X, since GMM requires <=2 dim, so I reshaped it

Comment: Ok. Can you please add some sample data which is causing this problem?

Comment: I used this image as the iput to the code:https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/BSDS300/html/images/plain/quarter/color/42049.jpg

Comment: Hi, Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

I think the reason has already been presented in the ErrorInformation, which is "because some components have ill-defined empirical covariance (for instance caused by singleton or collapsed samples)". Since you set the number of components to 2, it can not be decreased, so I suggest you to increase the parameter "reg_covar" to 1e-5 (default to 1e-6).

more information about GMM's parameters can be found in: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html